# How to Reset WebAuthn (FIDO) Dongle Password?

Tags: webauthn, fido-u2f, fido

I am implementing WebAuthn for my website and I set the `userVerification: "required"`.
I set a password on my dongle. How can I reset my dongle password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on mac os you can use the below link on your chrome device :

```
chrome://settings/securityKeys
```

then click on reset password.

Comment: Is this functionality available through WebAuthn or some other APIs? What if I wanted to build this functionality into me webapp?

Comment: checkout [this](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-ps-20190130/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-ps-20190130.html#authenticatorReset) link @spizzak

Comment: I implemented it using node js. If you need any help just ask :)